# how can i change date format to mmm-yy for cells ranging from A2: J2 in excel using python

Tags: python

I want to change date format of cell ranging from A2:J2

Its in format '2/1/2023 12:00:00 am' format but I want it in Feb-2023 format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to pip install the openpyxl package:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Then this code should work for you, make sure to update the file name for importing and exporting:

```
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime

# Load the workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('your_file.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

# Define a function to convert the date format
def convert_date_format(cell_value):
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(cell_value, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    return date_obj.strftime('%b-%Y')

# Loop through the range A2:J2
for col in range(1, 11):  # 1 to 10 corresponds to A to J
    cell = sheet.cell(row=2, column=col)
    
    # If the cell is not empty and has a date-like value
    if cell.value:
        try:
            cell.value = convert_date_format(cell.value)
        except ValueError:
            pass  # If it's not a date, do nothing

# Save changes
wb.save('updated_file.xlsx')
```

Comment: works well.. Just made small modification as my value was string type                              date_obj = datetime.strptime(str(cell_value), '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')